# Printing invoice to POS printer using jquery/javaScript or php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, printing, thermal-printer

i want to print invoice on AJAX response without opening print dialog box.
which library or plugin should i used for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You cant print without opening the print popup.
use jZebra library from google Jzebra [API](http://code.google.com/p/jzebra)

and use applet to print the receipt and your data should be in raw format

```
<input type=button onClick="print()" value="Print">
<applet name="jzebra" code="jzebra.PrintApplet.class" archive="./jzebra.jar" width="100" height="100">
  <param name="printer" value="zebra">
</applet>
<script>
  function print() {
   document.jzebra.append("PRINTED USING JZEBRA\n");
   document.jzebra.print();
  }
</script>
```

or

Print from the server. If this is a cloud server, ie not connectable to the receipt printer then what you can do is
From the server generate it as a pdf which can be made to popup a print dialog in the browser
Use something like Google Cloud Print which will allow connecting printers to a cloud service